# No target found for method thrown by Caliburn

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, caliburn

I'm trying to create an application which allows me to sketch some doodles on the canvas component with the help of Caliburn.Micro for MVVM. When I run the application and click on the Canvas I get "No target found for method OnMouseDown." exception. I defined the method to be called when the MouseDown event is called, but somehow Caliburn doesn't find it.

The project files are available here: [SketchingTool.zip](http://lotsovcookiez.com/SketchingTool.zip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I wired the application in a wrong way. The ViewModel it was looking for for methods was not the ViewModel they were in, because I mixed the view-first approach with the viewmodel-first approach. Fixing it according to the documentation of Caliburn fixed the problem.